# Codeigniter select data from multiple tables from database | no join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

So my question is:

Is it possible to select all data from different tables in one query?

Example1:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table1');
$query = $this->db->get('table2');
$query = $this->db->get('table3');

return $query->result();
```

Example2:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1', 'table2', 'table3');

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

I think the second exaple is possible. If not i want to ask how you would do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by putting the table names in an arrary

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from(['table1', 'table2'])
    ->get();
return $query->result();
```

But the number of rows in the result will be the product of the number of rows in each table, i.e. table1 has 3 rows and table2 has 19 you'll get 57 rows in the result. Are you sure that's what you want?

Joins are easy to write and highly efficient. Don't be afraid of them.